Positive part of the solution - relation between $B(u)$ and $B(u^+)$
Given $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, by Riesz Representation Theorem there exists a unique $B(u) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ weak solution of
$$
-\Delta v + v = u, \quad \mathbb{R}^N.
$$
Given $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, I know $u^+ \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and therefore there exists a unique $B(u^+)$ weak solution of
$$
-\Delta v + v = u^+, \quad \mathbb{R}^N.
$$
I wonder if is there a relation between $B(u)$ and $B(u^+)$. Any tip or comment is welcome.
